# What is the minimum amount of an AWS bill?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been using AWS (mostly S3 and Glacier) for a few years, but my usage is very low. Each month, I receive an invoice of $0.07, but Amazon never charges my credit card.

Is this because the amount is lower than the cost of processing the payment? Does Amazon just discard these, or are they accumulated and charged later?

Answer (score 4):

It seems plausible that the cost of processing a payment might prompt AWS to defer or discard very small invoices, but there is no public documentation that I'm aware of regarding a cutoff.

This question would best be referred to AWS support, particularly if you are concerned about your services being disrupted.

Answer (score -1):

Check this thread in AWS Developer Forums:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=227722#227722

My bill for May is saying I used 0.04 USD but the payment was waived.

[image]

I guess it does not make sense to charge for such small amounts. Imagine thousands of customers have accounts with usage below dollar.
Yes they could loose thousands of dollars but then again maybe they would pay even more for fees or pay for an accountant to manage those bills.